# Is it possible to use content of another website using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a Google chrome extension, where I need to take content of other website. I'm using jQuery because many suggested me to use it for Google extensions. Is it possible to take the content of another website using jQuery? If so, please show me how to do this.

If not, I have seen many Google extensions doing this. Can anybody tell me how to achieve it.

Comment: what have you tried so far? This site is to help with actual problems, not to do googling work for you. Also, your question is not very precise.

Comment: Look up `iframe`s and the jQuery `.load()` function

Comment: its now R  & D phase for me.

Comment: @jacktheripper: Thanks, seems to be answer, why don't you post it as answer.

Comment: @Pranit I think your rude answer deserves some appropriate reply: My comment is in no way destructive, far from that it's more constructive than posting a totally worthless answer because the question was too vague. It's not that I could not answer your question, it's about people not being willing to do research on their own but taking the lazy way and let others do their work. There are plenty of tutorials out there, how to build chrome-extensions. Maybe you should just starting searching and doing some work on your own. I think the downvotes and the close vote pretty much prove my POV.

Comment: If you would take a look at my profile you would notice I have enough reputation. Also I'm beyond that point where questions on stackoverflow would significantly increase my skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up `iframes` for a native HTML solution - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe

Alternatively, research using the jQuery `.load()` function - http://api.jquery.com/load/. However, the functionality of this is limited by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed in HTTP, this is some kind of cross side scripting :-D
You can only access content from your own domain! For example: Your site, that wants to display some data from another website is: www.yourdomain.com/mypage.html

Form myside.html you can only access resources (images, other html, etc.) from www.yourdomain.com ...

There are two ways to "display" content from another Website:

1. use Iframes in mypage.html
2. Let your webserver retrieve the
   other website, parse that data and generate the html for mypage.html
   with the data of the other website already integrated.

Comment: the question was about an extension, SOP does not apply here to the full extent as in normal webcontext.